# Django how to use array in template within a forloop

Tags: html, django

Im trying to use an array inside an html file within a loop

views

```
def noticia(request, noticia_id):
   noticia = get_object_or_404(Noticia, pk=noticia_id)
   user_like = False
   likes = []
   dislikes = []
   x = 0
   for comentario in noticia.comentario_set.all().order_by('-pub_data'):
       likes.append(0)
       dislikes.append(0)
   for comentario in noticia.comentario_set.all():
       for like in comentario.like_set.all():
           if like.like:
               likes[x] += 1
           elif like.dislike:
               dislikes[x] += 1
           if like.user == request.user:
               user_like = True
   return render(request, 'Bola/Noticia.html', {'noticia': noticia, 'user_like': user_like, 'likes': likes,
                                                'dislikes': dislikes})
```

Html

```
{% for comentario in noticia.comentario_set.all|dictsortreversed:"pub_data"%}
  {% for like in comentario.like_set.all %}
    <p>{{ likes.forloopcounter0 }} {{ dislikes.forloopcounter0 }}</p>
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a better way of doing it by using [Conditional Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation).

To use that, first lets update the ForeignKey relation between Comentario and Like using `related_name`:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comentario, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now use that related name in queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField

...

comments = noticia.comentario_set.all().annotate(
    like_count=Count(Case(
        When(likes__like=True, then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )).annotate(dislike_count=Count(Case(
        When(likes__like=False, then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
)

return render(request, 'Bola/Noticia.html', {'comments': comments})
```

Then use it in template:

```
{% for comentario in comments %}
   {{ comentario.like_count }}
   {{ comentario.dislike_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does this work for when multiple users, like the same comment?

Comment: Yes, it will count total likes of a single comment if `Like.like == True`